# Unrecognized Camera Parameters

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I have been always testing my Apps. on a device `Galaxy Note 2` and they were working fine. One of my Apps when I tried testing it on `Galaxy Note 3`, `logcat` generated the below posted errors. It is something related to the parameter of the camera but I don not know how to fix it, it is my first time to face such problem.

Logcat:

```
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
setParameters  
failed
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384):    at   
android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384):    at  
android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1606)
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384):    at
```

com.example.augrealtest02.SurfaceHolderActivity.surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolderActivity.java:60)
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:621)
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:93)
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:182)
01-01 16:24:51.119: E/AndroidRuntime(13384):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:864)

Code:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters camParameter = this.myCamera.getParameters();
    //camParameter.setSceneMode(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_ACTION);
    //camParameter.setColorEffect(Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
    //camParameter.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
    camParameter.setPreviewSize(width/2, height/2);
    camParameter.setPictureSize(width/2, height/2);
    //myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    myCamera.setParameters(camParameter);
    myCamera.startPreview();
}
```